# cPickle.dump(gmm, open(dest + picklefile, 'w')) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python

help me please

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "E:/Speaker-Identification-Python-master/Speaker-Identification-Python-master/modeltraining.py", line 49, in  cPickle.dump(gmm, open(dest + picklefile, 'w'))
>   TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: You should include more context with your question, such as the relevant portion of `modeltraining.py`, and explain more of what you're trying to accomplish.  That being said, you may be able to overcome this particular error by opening your file in byte mode ('wb')

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You are using the wrong file mode for pickling. Pickling converts objects to bytes, not string. The 'w' or 'write' mode will open the file in string mode. Change it to 'wb' to open the file in the 'write-binary' mode. Change `cPickle.dump(gmm, open(dest + picklefile, 'w'))` to `cPickle.dump(gmm, open(dest + picklefile, 'wb'))`